# Exception from which gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, logging

I want a rails 3.2 app to log which gem owns the code, where an exception occur.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print out the execution stack by $ERROR_INFO.caller and find out where the exception occurs.

Comment: So you suggest that I figure out the gem by looking at the path?